# Adding new column with multiple values per existing record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm interested in adding a column to an existing table with a set of explicit values that should duplicate existing records (similar to common join constructs).

For example, say we're starting with a table with a single column:

```
CREATE TABLE #DEMO (
    COLUMN_A NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (COLUMN_A)
);
```

| COLUMN_A |
| --- |
| ACCOUNT_001 |
| ACCOUNT_002 |
| ACCOUNT_003 |

...and I want to add Column_B with row values of 'A', 'B', and 'C'.  The end goal would be a table that looks like:

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B |
| --- | --- |
| ACCOUNT_001 | A |
| ACCOUNT_001 | B |
| ACCOUNT_001 | C |
| ACCOUNT_002 | A |
| ACCOUNT_002 | B |
| ACCOUNT_002 | C |
| ACCOUNT_003 | A |
| ACCOUNT_003 | B |
| ACCOUNT_003 | C |

Is this possible?  Bonus Points if there is a name or phrase for this you know of.

Comment: When you say you want to add a column, are you saying you want to modify the table structure? Or are you describing the resultset you want with a select query?

Comment: CROSS JOIN a subquery that prodices A,B,C

Comment: You would have to drop the primary key constraint first.

Comment: Bonus points when you clarify your question such that it makes sense.

Comment: @DaleK Apologies for the delay in response, I was feeding my kiddo.  

In this scenario the table structure is indeed being modified; I'm starting with a single column table, adding a new column, and populating that new column with an explicit list of values across all existing records with the desire for existing records in the first column to be repeated accordingly.

The final table in the question is the desired final table, but if you know of a better method with a SELECT Query that I could dump into a Temp Table I'd be very interested to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you need couple of steps to first insert new rows and then update existing:

```
alter table #demo add COLUMN_B char(1);

with x as (
    select * from (values('A'),('B'))x(B)
)
insert into #demo(COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B)
select COLUMN_A, B
from #DEMO cross join x

update #DEMO set COLUMN_B = 'C'
where COLUMN_B is null
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81a617560222ac951350020236281575)

Comment: Sincere thanks Stu!  This was exactly the sort of solution I was looking for.  Thanks for taking the time to share.